# How can I use GRPC versioning in a code-first approach?

Tags: .net, code-first, grpc-dotnet

As you can see in *[Versioning gRPC services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/versioning?view=aspnetcore-7.0)*, in GRPC we can use versioning by defining `package` in a `proto` file.

How can I achieve the same functionality in a code-first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some approaches for meeting your requirements.

First with `Service[greet.V1]`:

```
namespace BSN.Resa.Cas.AppService.Contract
{
    [ServiceContract("BSN.Resa.Cas.V1")]
    public interface ICaptchaQueryService
    {
        Task<Response<CaptchaVerifyViewModel>> VerifyAsync(CaptchaQueryServiceVerifyRequest request);
    }
}
```

Second with `namespace gree.V1`:

```
namespace BSN.Resa.Cas.AppService.Contract.V1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICaptchaQueryService
    {
        Task<Response<CaptchaVerifyViewModel>> VerifyAsync(CaptchaQueryServiceVerifyRequest request);
    }
}
```

Third, you can change the name `interface` to combine with a version, for example, `ICaptchaQueryService` to `ICaptchaQueryServiceV1`.

In the end, you can combine some of above methods together as you need.